# I registered my service with Eureka using spring boot but cant able to launch or access the service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I registered my  service with Eureka. Even Eureka dashboard showing my service.
But when i try to access the client from browser i can't able to get the response and browser gives site can't be reached. Is there anything I missed or anything wrong here. I tried http://movie-catlog:8086/catlog

**Eureka code and Properties:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

**Properties**

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Service Main Class:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MovieCatlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieCatlogApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate getRestTemp()
    {return new RestTemplate();}

    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder getWebclient()
    {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

**Properties:**

```
spring.application.name=movie-catlog
server.port=8086
```

**Pom for server**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**pom for client:**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I also tried by adding **eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/** at the client side but same result. But in Eureka dashboard I can able to see the results that and  my service are up and showing there For reference i adding console and Eureka [image] [image]

Comment: Have you tried to visit the URL `http://movie-catlog:8086/catlog` with host replaced by IP?

Comment: @LHCHIN I used three services 2 of them are calling internally using rest template. Internal calls are working fine .But the main service  one from web browser is not working. Main(catlog) service  one is working using IP but not with application name. Internal rest calls are working with application name.

Comment: Could you post more screeshots? Because I don't think that it works for internal calls by directly using RestTemplate with application name as host. AS far as I know, `@FeignClient` is the only way for internal calls with application name.

Comment: @LHCHIN I am using Loadbalanced annotations which looks the registered services with eureka. So for every call it look for eureka and discovers the service. But the direct call from browser has no way to discover the service using application name. So it uses the IP and internal resttemplate calls uses the loadbalanced anonnation discover the service from eureka. My understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Unless you registered the application name to your DNS, you cannot visit the URL directly by its application name as host.

Comment: Exactly same issue i am facing . Any suggestion what to do? @PrithiviThiyagu

Comment: @TanmaySahoo  to access the service registred with eureka you can either use  api call or to access directly browser its only possible with ip  of your service, can't access them with the name of the service. If facing any other issue share screenshot

Comment: Thank you @Prithivi Thiyagu . It's been solved.